# GridView SelectedItem indicator not present on Windows Phone Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

on Windows 8.1 below code indicates the selected item of GridView. But on Windows Phone Xaml same code doesn't work like that. There isn't any visual indicator for selected item at all.(or i couldn't get it to work) How can i make it work like this on Windows Phone App too?

[image]

```
<GridView
  x:Name="productColorChoices"
  SelectionMode="Single"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource productColorChoice_ItemTemplate}">
  <GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VariableSizedWrapGrid
          Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go look at the [GridViewItem default style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709915.aspx) you'll see towards the bottom you have these objects in there;

> SelectedBorder
>
> SelectedCheckMarkOuter
>
> SelectedCheckMark
>
> SelectedEarmark

Which is what makes up the visuals for that selected outline/checkmark thingy on the GridView items. They all get shown according to the VisualState for `Selected`

Now, if you go and look at the phone's default style template for the GridViewItem's (which I couldn't find the default one for with a quick google search and I don't have a phone project open to go dig through) then you can compare. If these types of elements don't exist in the phone templates then you can go add them the same way using pretty much the same objects and the same storyboards in the same VisualState.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Share what you tried, we can help you fix it. You'll need to expose the default style template for the gridviewitem for the  phone though.

Comment: I used DataTemplateSelector and added a isSelected bool to my objects. Now it works fine but feels a little weird.

Comment: @garenyondem Not sure why you'd need a template selector, but yea each item does have an IsSelected property...but then again I guess I don't know what your overall goal was.